# node.js - How can I use jsdom / node-jquery to update what my pages look like?

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io, multiplayer, jsdom

It seems that all of the documentation that I could find on `jsdom` were about ["scraping oher people's pages"](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/) for information. I want to use either `jsdom` or `node-jquery` to update the page that the user is on. I know that when I write the code, I could just have a regular `<script>` tag that linked to a JavaScript file in the public directory, but I want to learn how to do it from the server if that is even possible. What I really want is to allow multiple users to connect to a page and have the page update for all users when one user does an action. For example, button 1 turns the background black. Button 2 turns it red, and button 3 turns it white. And correct me if I'm wrong, but I don't think that's possible by linking to a JavaScript file via a `<script>` tag. So looking at `jsdom`:

```
jsdom.env({html: ???, src: jquery, done: callback });
```

Ok so here is **problem number 1**. I have no idea what to put for html in this bit of code to get my DOM objects, or what I can do. My files are written in jade, so I can't just load them from a file. Then I started thinking that maybe I can put this piece of code in the routing portion of my code and get the html from the `req` variable. So I started playing around in my routing code:

```
exports.index = function(){
  res.render('index', {title: 'MyTitle'});
};
```

And let me just say that this whole routing thing is already blowing my mind up. I have tried to `res.render` a second time, but that doesn't work. So that leads to **problem number 2**. Even if I could get the DOM objects and manipulate them, I don't know how I would push them back to the clients because doing a second `res.render` doesn't work. Not to mention that would defeat the purpose because I might as well redirect them to another page if I was making them re-render.

I am planning on using `socket.io` to handle the users connections so maybe the key lies there. Maybe I could set a `socket.on('button_click', function(){ ... });` but I have no idea what to put inside that function to handle the DOM manipulation and update of the DOM, or how on the client side to have the button emit `'button_click'` because the client doesn't have access to the socket.io variable.

So if someone could help explain these things to me using examples that would be so great. I really have tried to figure all of this out, I've spent a few days researching and reading the  API docs of node.js, express.js, socket.io, jsdom, and node-jquery. It just seems that all of the examples I find are very basic to just their own sphere and there are no examples that really tie them together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going in a slightly awkward direction.

First, if you've used jade, it uses the jade compiler to compile into html.

Second, once you've compiled it, you can push it into jsdom as it uses an html5 parser, and then you can manipulate it via the normal DOM apis.

Third, you don't have access to the DOM in your clients browsers directly. Normally the way people go about implementing something like a shared synchronous view is to use socket.io and transmit data events down to each client, where you write client side javascript that interpret those events and make the requisite changes in the UI. You are sending down a set of html and javascript that is bootstrapping each client -- rarely do people keep a full DOM in memory on the server and then try to update it and broadcast changes down to the clients. You *could* do this, I just wouldn't recommend it. Not usually how things are structured.

Fourth, its pretty complicated to do this on a first pass here. I recommend looking at a client side mvc framework comparison app like todomvc -- http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/. Look at the source of each, including the plain old javascript version. This will teach you enough to understand the client side part of this. Then you can imagine using something like socket.io to update your models and build views that depend on change events from those models. You can do all this without mvc, but it teaches you good separation of concerns and such to learn how people typically structure these types of applications.

Comment: Your third point, is what really helped me the most. I redesigned my code to use `socket.on()` and `socket.emit()`. So the users aren't actually connected to the same page, but the JavaScript on the client-side give the illusion that they are. Thanks. :)